# Customize minimum and maximum value for logi.hist.plot in R

Tags: r

Anybody know how to set the minimum and maximum values for x-axis when running `logi.hist.plot` in popbio package in R?

At the moment, the minimum value is defined as my minimum data value. I want it to be 0.

```
library(popbio)
logi.hist.plot(data$Heat, data$Death, logi.mod = 1,
               boxp = FALSE,type="hist", col="gray",
               ylabel = "Probability of death", 
               ylabel2 = "Death Frequency",
               xlabel = "Heat", 
               mainlabel = "Logistic probability plot of Heat vs Death")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not offered a dataset for testing possible solutions to this request, but I offer an idea:

First make a plot that basically sets up the desired limits with xlim and ylim as desired, and blank x- and y-labels and axt="n",

...then issue `par(new=TRUE)`,

...then run your plot function.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at the source code - just type `logi.hist.plot` -  it isn't possible to change the axis limits.

The source code is fairly long, but not that complicated. Essentially, the `boxp=FALSE` option calls this part of code:

```
logi.scater <- function(independ, depend, scater = "n", x.lab = xlabel, 
        las = las.h) {
      plot(independ, depend, cex = 1, type = scater, ylab = ylabel, 
           xlab = x.lab, main = mainlabel, cex.lab = 1.2, las = las)
}
```

You can see that the `plot` function doesn't allow limits to be passed.

You options are:

1. Take apart the source code and construct your own plot.
2. Decided you are happy with the axis.